# Why is ORDER BY conflicting in a UNION ALL with multiple SELECT query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an OQL query (simplified SQL) which at the ends is executed as SQL.

The idea is do a query with a where constraingt and do for the same query a total summarization, also with the where constraint, and join these 2 tables together as one table (with at the end the total).

Strange enough I can not execute the whole query with the order by function, while without that, it is executed well. I get the following error:ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "MSM".

This is my code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT msm.matrixid                                                                                                                                                         AS matrixid,
                gp.mainvob                                                                                                                                                           AS policy,
                gp.debtorname                                                                                                                                                        AS debtorname,
                msm.debtornumber_ms                                                                                                                                                  AS debtornumber,
                msm.periodstring                                                                                                                                                     AS period,
                '€ '+Round(Sum (Cast (grosspremiumamount_ms AS      DECIMAL)),2)                                                                                                   AS sumgrosspremiumamount,
                '€ '+Round(Sum (Cast (brokerageamount_ms AS         DECIMAL)),2)                                                                                                   AS sumbrokerageamountcontinuance,
                '€ '+Round(Sum (Cast (signingcommissionamount_ms AS DECIMAL)),2)                                                                                                   AS sumsigningcommissionamount,
                '€ '+Round(Sum (Cast (grosspremiumamount_ms AS      DECIMAL)) - Sum (Cast (brokerageamount_ms AS DECIMAL)) - Sum (Cast (signingcommissionamount_ms AS DECIMAL)),2) AS sumnetpremiumamount,
                0                                                                                                                                                                    AS union_order
FROM            matching.marketscanmovement MSM 
INNER JOIN      msm/matching.marketscanmovement_geraspolicy/matching.geraspolicy gp 
WHERE           msm.debtornumber_ms='P29000024' 
AND             transactiontype='Premium_endorsement' 
OR              transactiontype='Premium_renewal' 
GROUP BY        msm.periodstring, 
                msm.matrixid, 
                gp.mainvob, 
                gp.debtorname, 
                msm.debtornumber_ms 
UNION ALL 
SELECT     ''                                                                                                                                                                   AS matrixid,
           ''                                                                                                                                                                   AS policy,
           ''                                                                                                                                                                   AS debtorname,
           ''                                                                                                                                                                   AS debtornumber,
           'Total'                                                                                                                                                              AS period,
           '€ '+round(sum (cast (grosspremiumamount_ms AS      decimal)),2)                                                                                                   AS sumgrosspremiumamount,
           '€ '+round(sum (cast (brokerageamount_ms AS         decimal)),2)                                                                                                   AS sumbrokerageamountcontinuance,
           '€ '+round(sum (cast (signingcommissionamount_ms AS decimal)),2)                                                                                                   AS sumsigningcommissionamount,
           '€ '+round(sum (cast (grosspremiumamount_ms AS      decimal)) - sum (cast (brokerageamount_ms AS decimal)) - sum (cast (signingcommissionamount_ms AS decimal)),2) AS sumnetpremiumamount,
           1                                                                                                                                                                    AS union_order
FROM       matching.marketscanmovement msm 
INNER JOIN msm/matching.marketscanmovement_geraspolicy/matching.geraspolicy gp 
WHERE      ( 
                      debtornumber_ms='P29000024' 
           AND        transactiontype='Premium_endorsement' 
           OR         transactiontype='Premium_renewal') 
ORDER BY   union_order, 
           period , 
           msm.matrixid, 
           gp.mainvob, 
           gp.debtorname, 
           msm.debtornumber_ms
```

I found similar questions that it has to do with the ordering of the select statements with the order by statement, but could not figure out what exactly.

Can anytone tell me pls what I am doing wrong and how the expected behaviour should be?

Comment: If you append to a query in parenthesis, the closing parenthesis should be at the end of the appended string not at its beginning...

Comment: Sorry the parenthesis were not in the original query, now it is the original query..can you explain now what you mean?

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add a [mcve]. That is the tables' structure as `CREATE TABLE` statements, sample data for the tables as `INSERT INTO` statements and the desired result for that sample data. Wouldn't harm if you tagged the version of your DBMS as well.

Comment: You've still not posted your actual SQL statement. What you've posted is littered with syntax errors. Please post your **actual code** if you want us to help figure out why it's not working. It's also highly unlikely that you're using both MySQL and PostgreSQL simultaneously; if you're not, then remove the tag that does not apply.

Comment: I am using a framework that is not showing the SQL statement friend, what can I do

Comment: Debugging is part of programmers job.  Have you tried running the queries individually to make sure both work?

Comment: You say you're using "OQL" and "a framework that is not showing the SQL statement". You should tag the answer with the name of the framework and indicate what kind of product(s) and version(s) you're using

Comment: That is invalid SQL for Postgres (Postgres uses the standard `||` operator for string concatenation, not `+` - that is for adding numbers in SQL). Are you sure you are using Postgres?

Answer (score 0):

Between these two lines:

```
INNER JOIN      msm/matching.marketscanmovement_geraspolicy/matching.geraspolicy gp
WHERE           msm.debtornumber_ms='P29000024'
```

you need an ON clause

```
ON msm.something = gp.something
```

Answer (score 0):

you have several errors in your query.

Starting with order by, you can't reference aliases in the order by (at least not for a union), you must use column names or ordinal positions:

```sql
ORDER BY   union_order, 
           period , 
           matrixid, 
           mainvob, 
           debtorname, 
           debtornumber_ms
```

or

```sql
ORDER BY 10, 5, ...
```

next, even if not required, you should put brackets around your boolean operators - **especially when you mix AND & OR.**

for example, you have:

```sql
WHERE      ( 
                      debtornumber_ms='P29000024' 
           AND        transactiontype='Premium_endorsement' 
           OR         transactiontype='Premium_renewal')
```

This will run as

```sql
where
   (debtornumber_ms ='P29000024' AND transactiontype='Premium_endorsement' )
  OR (transactiontype='Premium_renewal')
```

In other words, you will get all "Premium_Renewals" plus debtor "P2900024" only if they have "Premium_Endorsement".

Probably that is not what you are after. Probably you mean to get debtor P2900024 if they are "premium_endorsement" or "premium_renewal". In which case you can do this:

```sql
where
   debtornumber_ms ='P29000024' AND ( 
        transactiontype='Premium_endorsement' OR transactiontype='Premium_renewal'
   )
```

or more simply:

```sql
where
   debtornumber_ms ='P29000024' AND
   transactiontype in ('Premium_endorsement', 'Premium_renewal')
```

You are also missing an `ON` clause and join conditions on your two `INNER JOIN` clauses. That is the most likely cause of the error you have posted.